# Is it a good idea to bind SelectedItem of a tab control with MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I wanted to know which tab is selected in a tab control. I am using MVVM.

I know that I can bind the SelectedIndex of the tab control, but I also can bind the selectedItem, that it is a TabItem object.

I have read that the view model shouldn't know about the view, and many times read that this means doesn't use objects of types that belongs to the view. So in this case, TabItem is an object that belongs to the view space, so I am wondering if it would be a good idea to bind to SelectedItem.

However, the advise to not bind types that belongs to the view, I understand more than that view model shouldn't to depend on the structure or the behaviour of the view, to separate both parts. However, from some point of view, TabItem is just an object, that I use in an isolate way (I am not tiding the view model to the view). I use tabItem as any other object.

So my question is, in MVVM is it really a bad idea to use a TabItem in my view model?

EDIT: I add the code of my tab control:

```
                        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <TabItem Header="Persons" Content="{Binding Persons}"/>
                            <TabItem Header="Cities" Content="{Binding Cities}"/>
```

I have a user control for persons and other user control for cities.

Comment: When you manually write different `<TabItem>`s then : yes it is a bad idea. Binding SelectedIndex would not be great but could be usable in that case. Binding  Selecteditem only makes sense when you also bind ItemsSource to something,  see @d.moncada's answer.

Comment: So how does `{Binding Persons}` result in a UserControl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `SelectedItem` is definitely a good idea. On a `TabControl`, the `SelectedItem` will bind to the data type of the `TabControl`s data source.

Example:

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControl1"
                    Margin="10"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}">
</TabControl>

public class ViewModel
{
    private Employee _selectedEmployee;

    public IList<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }

    public Employee SelectedEmployee
    {
        get { return _selectedEmployee; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedEmployee == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedEmployee = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel will not know anything about the UI data type, it only knows about the underlying data (the SelectedEmployee).

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc672537(v%3Dvs.95)

Comment: A correct answer but not complete. You ought to add the DataTemplate for hooking up the TabItem with an EmployeeView.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I assumed  he already had that information set up. I can add that too

Comment: really each tab in my control is a diferent type, so if you could give a more detail example, I would thank you so much. Because I don't know if Employee is view or view model. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Employee is the ViewModel. How does your DataSource look if each tab is a different type? Unless, you have hard-coded tabs? Post your XAML

Comment: I mean that a tabitem has user control for persons, and other tabitem has a user control for cities. They are diferents views and diferents view models.